# How to select value of a tag which is generated dynamically using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to convert a XML file to CSV but my Problem is that I don't know how to select a tag whose parent tag is generated dynamically and it may come multiple time with the same name but the content of it varies, I mean ComponentDetails tag may appear for each employee one or more times.
In my case for the staffNumber 12345 ComponentDetails appear 2 times and for staffNumber 45555 ComponentDetails 3 times, and I want to select value from the salary tag but unable to identify it. I have assigned ID to the tag but 
the main problem is that as the ComponentDetails varies so I fail to figure out at what position which ComponentType will appear.

My XML file is as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root>
    <PayrunDetails>
        <PayrunNumber>000777</PayrunNumber>
        <PaidDate>2018-05-15</PaidDate>
    </PayrunDetails>
    <PayLocation>
        <LocationCode>ACT</LocationCode>
        <LocationDescription>ACT</LocationDescription>
        <CompanyDetails>
            <CCode>APPLE</CCode>
            <CName>APPLE Limited</CName>
            <Payslip>
                <StaffNumber>12345</StaffNumber>
                <BankDetails>
                    <BankAccountNo>121212</BankAccountNo>
                </BankDetails>
                <PayDetails>
                    <PayType>NORMAL</PayType>
                    <AmountGross>9999</AmountGross>
                    <ComponentDetails ID="1">
                        <ComponentType>SALARY</ComponentType>
                        <Amount>1999</Amount>
                        <YTDAmount>10616</YTDAmount>
                    </ComponentDetails>
                    <ComponentDetails ID="3">
                        <ComponentType>TAXABLE</ComponentType>
                        <Amount>505</Amount>
                        <YTDAmount>7703</YTDAmount>
                    </ComponentDetails>
                </PayDetails>
            </Payslip>
            <Payslip>
                <StaffNumber>45555</StaffNumber>
                <BankDetails>
                    <BankAccountNo>131313</BankAccountNo>
                </BankDetails>
                <PayDetails>
                    <PayType>NORMAL</PayType>
                    <AmountGross>9999</AmountGross>
                    <ComponentDetails ID="1">
                        <ComponentType>SALARY</ComponentType>
                        <Amount>1999</Amount>
                        <YTDAmount>10616</YTDAmount>
                    </ComponentDetails>
                    <ComponentDetails ID="2">
                        <ComponentType>GROSS</ComponentType>
                        <Amount>7305</Amount>
                        <YTDAmount>76703</YTDAmount>
                    </ComponentDetails>
                    <ComponentDetails ID="3">
                        <ComponentType>TAXABLE</ComponentType>
                        <Amount>305</Amount>
                        <YTDAmount>6703</YTDAmount>
                    </ComponentDetails>
                </PayDetails>
            </Payslip>
        </CompanyDetails>
    </PayLocation>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see, `ComponentDetails` elements are part of your **source XML**.
They are not generated dynamically, at least you did't post any XSLT
script that generated them.

If each `PayDetails` element contained only a single `ComponentDetails`,
you could refer to it in XSLT using just its name.

But since it contains multiple `ComponentDetails` and you want to refer
to the "salary" element **only**, you can write:

```
select="ComponentDetails[ComponentType='SALARY']"
```

Comment: Hi Valdi_Bo,I don;t have source of XML, my task is to extract some details from the xml file and convert it in to the CSV format, so while converting the file to csv if found few tags is coming multiple times and it contains different information, in my case ComponentDetails has come multiple times and inside this there is a sub-tag ComponentType contains information relevant to ComponentDetails but I don't know how do I select this field.

Comment: One I thing I can do to resolve this problem that if I put the Amount, YTDAmount  inside the ComponentDetails tag, but I don't know how to change range of a tag span of an XML file.